# JetBrains Rider doesn't evaluate expression

Tags: debugging, ide, jetbrains-ide, rider, evaluate

I am trying to execute an expression in Rider 2019.3.3, Dot NET version - 5.0.1. But any expressions evaluated with errors, even the simplest.

[image: Error evaluate]

Comment: For newest dotnet, you'd likely need the newest Rider.

Comment: @IvanShakhov I tried Rider version 2020.2.4, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You'd need 2020.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the new version solved the problem.